# How can I generate multiple comments with the method " this.Application.ActiveDocument.Comments.Add " for VSTO Add-in projects for Word?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, vsto, docx

sorry for interrupting,

I'm quite new with C# and VisualStudio. I'm trying to automate a process of **checking paragraphs and then commenting these paragraphs in word files (.docx)** using the **VSTO for word files in Visual Studio 2019**.

Right now my code **open the word file and create one single comment for the first paragraph**. **My issue** is that I would like to **have multiple paragraphs in the word file and generate the "same" comment for each paragraph.**

When I change the range of [1] to [2] in the method posted below, I just generate a comment in the second paragraph. I**f I change the range as far as I understand to [1,2] it's says that the method doesn't accept more that one - only argument**, I haven't find any documentation regarding to generate multiples comments for .docx or using/modify the range of the method to generate the same comment for multiple content/different paragraphs.

This method I'm trying **to modify:**

**this.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range,ref text)**

I'm using this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-add-comments-to-text-in-documents?view=vs-2017
My code just open/read the files and generate one single comment in the paragraph given by the range " [1] "

I've created a random word file called NewDocument.docx and just write two random sentences in different paragraphs to testing.

Code:

```
this.Application.Documents.Open(@"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx", ReadOnly:true);

object text = "That's a simple paragraph.";


this.Application.ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(



this.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range,ref text)
```

I would really appreciated if someone could you help me with! Many thanks!

Comment: I have an example project I've forked in GitHub that might help you out.  https://github.com/Word-projects/Word-Editing-Tools

Comment: Thanks! I'll check if works! but I'm looking how to change the range of the method:  this.Application.ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(
this.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range,ref text) so I can generate the same comment for multiples paragraphs